# Problem with Minecraft Skins and Texture packs on multi user Kindle Fire

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son has a Kindle Fire, which we have set up for multiple users. Mine is an adult account and I manage his child account. He has been using Minecraft PE. This weekend, we downloaded Skins and Texture packs, which appear in my account, but are not available to him in his account. Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: I would reccommend talking to their customer service.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because on Kindle Fires the child account may have less privileges than the Adult account. This could probably be fixed in the Kindle Adult Monitoring Profiles page.